# How to trick PHP into thinking my absolute path would be different?

Tags: php, function, webserver

My hosting service sets my absolute path in php to "/customers/12345/BASEPATHOFMYWEBSPACE" so, i have to enter "/customers/12345/BASEPATHOFMYWEBSPACE/MYFOLDER" to get to MYFOLDER, but in html "/MYFOLDER" totally works.

because of the way my site is structured, this is a huge problem for me...

is there a way i could come up with a function, i would then include in all my php files that would trick php into accepting "/MYFOLDER" as the absolute path to MYFOLDER?

Comment: did you hear anything about relative paths?

Comment: i can't use relative paths, because of the way my site works

Comment: ref: [chdir](http://php.net/manual/function.chdir.php)

Comment: This is because the browser path and and the absolute path are completely different things. The best answer is to not use absolute paths at all but just use relative paths. Any other answer is going to confuse the hell out of anyone who has to try and work out your code in the future (yourself included)

Comment: `__DIR__` gets the location of your script. I hope this helps.

Comment: so, if i would use chdir('/customers/12345/') in every php file, i could just use relative paths to my base directory, is that correct?

Comment: `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is a huge problem for me...

But this is just how it is - it's not specific to your hosting provider. If you can't get your head around the difference between URL paths and filesystem paths, then you're going to have lots of problems.

Chances are the webserver already knows the difference - have a look at the output of phpinfo().

If you've got your own vhost, I suspect you'll find that "/customers/12345/BASEPATHOFMYWEBSPACE" = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

So if you want to map a URL to filesystem path:

```
function to_file_path($url)
{
   $parts=parse_url($url);
   return $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $parts['path']
}
```

and conversely:

```
function to_url_path($file)
{
  $file=realname($file);
  if (substr($file, 0, strlen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]))
        !==$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) {
     return false;
  }
  return substr($file, strlen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if php `safe_mode` is enabled you can use `ini_set()` or `set_include_path()` to alter the include_path.

This would allow you to use relative paths after that.  For example in your site's configuration (or some other file that gets included by all pages) you could do this:

```
<?php
// This will allow all files to have relative path access to the
// "/customers/12345/BASEPATHOFMYWEBSPACE/MYFOLDER" directory.
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "/customers/12345/BASEPATHOFMYWEBSPACE/MYFOLDER");

// Eg: now you can write require('myfile.php') and
// it will search inside of "/customers/12345/BASEPATHOFMYWEBSPACE/MYFOLDER"
```

Comment: Whilst this would work for including files, I do not believe it would work for manipulating files on the filesystem. The OP has not given any details of what functionality they use which requires absolute paths. Just thought I should mention that caveat